# Using my StackExchange account name and profile link in an MIT licence, as <copyright holder>

Tags: discussion, profile-page, hyperlinks

I don't want to use my real name in some software I have developed and distributed, therefore I want to use `<my_user_name>` along with a link to my SE account.

E.g. in an MIT license:

> The MIT License (MIT)
> Copyright (c) 2016 <my_user_name> (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4230591?tab=profile)
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation [...]

I'm not a lawyer and not familiar with licences, so is Stack Exchange OK with that?

Comment: I'm not sure SO/SE has any say in this. And for example in the case of written works, it is perfectly acceptable to use a pseudonym/pen-name without somehow losing your copyright.

Comment: @Bart Yes, I knew about the pseudonym but wasn't sure about the link. Reading the "no endorsement" statements on so many licences, i thought i d better ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking about specifically, but…*

- Would Stack Exchange object to linking to your SE account in an MIT License?

I don't see why we would.

- Is it a valid way to identify yourself in an MIT License?

That's more a question for a lawyer or the MIT folks behind the license. It wouldn't seem to cause any problems with *our* Terms of Service or the licensing of content you post *here.*

**But please note:** Any content posted *here* is licensed under a non-revocable Creative Commons license ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), or [earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344491/an-update-on-creative-commons-licensing)), which means you cannot remove that license from your content *here*. You can, however, add an *additional* license by stating that you are granting the additional license (e.g. by adding a notation to your profile). In such case, users would have the option to choose which license they used for your content which is found *here on Stack Exchange*. (However, I'm not sure if that is part of what you are asking, though.)

Comment: I was only asking about using my SE name plus SE profile link as a `<copyright placeholders>` in the [MIT licence](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) (it's at the top of the licence text). My contributions to SE are irrelevant (besides i've dual licenced those under CC0).